# spring-boot-starter-parent AND spring version

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm developing a Java spring web service application. The application has a maven multi module layout, containing a webapp module - and a client module with a retrofit client.

I want to use the spring boot starter to manage my dependencies - and thus my webapp has the entry:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

My client needs some Spring types - and this dependency would suufice:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Is there anyway to couple these versions?

Comment: Spring boot parent already manages the spring framework versions in use, although it may not call it out as managed spring boot is built to specific version of spring framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring Boot without the parent.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

So you could add the dependency management to your own parent POM and both modules can use that as parent.